# Google Maps missing row of tiles on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, maps

Following problem:

I'm trying to style the print view of a website containing a custom google map.
In the print view and only on Chrome there is a row of tiles missing. This does not happen for all maps on other pages, just certain ones.
I can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?
[Horizontal Cut / Missing tile row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ZYE.png)

Comment: Please detail more clearly the nature of your problem, provide some of the relevant code you use to style the page, and what have you tried so far to fix it. Explain what does it mean "only certain maps" (what characteristics do they have).

Comment: The maps are all being implemented the same way. Just the map location differs. The maps work on the actual page, just once i switch to the print preview the problem occurs. (and only on chrome)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3550 Found this, seems to be a common problem only solved by putting the map on a different page and including it with an iframe.

Answer (score 8):

Although this question is quite old I thought I'd post a solution that worked for me in case anyone stumbles upon this question like I have.

Adding a few lines of CSS seems to fix this Google Maps painting issue:

```
.gm-style div > img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Thanks to the author of comment 13 on [this chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426294) for offering this solution.